# JQUERY autocomplete and asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, autocomplete

how can i use this script:
http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

with a web service?

Thanks!

Comment: The site you linked to has docs and examples.  Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Did you figure it out, or do you need more help?  If you are OK at this point please accept answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the .cfm cold fusion module is a replacement for the web service... So effectively you can't without rewriting it.

There is an example of jQuery for what you want to do here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Jquery_Autocomplete.aspx

look at the "AutoComplete: Data from a Webservice" section.  The example is in asp.net, however you can set up a similar web service using any language which allows it (PHP, c++ etc).